# How do I display all months with the 5 latest posts?

Tags: wordpress

I need to display all the months that have active posts, and inside each month I need to display at least 5 posts that are tied to each month.. the HTML will look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Souvlaki ignitus carborundum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Defacto lingo est igpay atinlay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quote meon an estimate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Souvlaki ignitus carborundum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Defacto lingo est igpay atinlay</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Quote meon an estimate</a></li>
</ul>
<h6>April:</h6>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sic tempus fugit esperanto hiccup</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Epsum factorial non deposit</a></li>
</ul>
<h6>May</h6>
```

How would I go about this or what function(s) could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<?php for ($i=1; i<12; $i++)
{
    $month=$i;
    $nQuery = new WP_Query("monthnum=$month&order=ASC&posts_per_page=5" );
    if (nQuery->have_posts()) : while (nQuery->have_posts()) : nQuery->the_post(); ?>
    //INSERT PREFFERED DATA HERE!!!
}?>
```